# Ajax Error Handling - Success and failure

Tags: ajax

We will face 4 errors

1. Server side error (page not found)
2. Run time error (nullpointerexception)
3. Business error (specified name doesn't exist)
4. Form validation errors (Invalid input)

There are two functions available in each ajax call. success and failure calls

```
ex:

$.ajax({
  success: function(){
  },
  error: function() {
      // ????
  }
  });
```

Does failure handles all above of the above?

Does failure will gets called in all of the above cases ?

Thank.s

Comment: The error will trigger for your first one, but for the rest, it will only trigger based on the way API is handled, like if for `null pointer exception` your API can return with an error code of `503` or something like that. If it returns with such error code then it will surely enter in the error section

Comment: Does error function will always gets called if there is an error code associated with it ?? For any request there will be always an error code no matter whether the API sets or not...is that right or wrong ?

Comment: Any feedback, Aswin Ramesh ???

Comment: yes, error function will trigger when an HTTP error occurs, such as API fail with `500` or `404` or etc...

Comment: Thank you for the answer..we can resolve this